# How to edit a table on a specific time automatically with js, PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, timing

I have a table on MySQL database which holds a hotel's customers data.For ex:

```
Name   |check-in date| duration
--------------------------------
Dan    |28.09.2012   | 5 days  
Robert |30.09.2012   | 2 days  
Sue    |01.10.2012   | 3 days
```

duration holds how many days will customer stay at the hotel. The thing I want to do is updating table automatically(to delete rows when the leaving time comes).
For ex: Robert will leave 30.09.2012 + 2 days = 02.10.2012
I want to delete that row automatically on 02.10.2012.
How can I do that by using JavaScript, PHP and MySQL?

Comment: have a look at cron jobs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron
You can for example write a php script which does what you want, and call that script once a day with a cron job.

Comment: Which version of mysql you are using?

Comment: MySQL Events are supported after 5.1 version

Answer (score 0):

Try to setup cron job. You will get more help here-
http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to delete that row, just change status (enable to disable). 
You can also use ajax to delete row .
or tell me some thing about your cpanel then I can help you to set cron.

Comment: Helllo social engineering!

Comment: :D , Dear friend Itai  , I am not saying user to give me your cpanel credentials , just I want to know about cpanel type then I can provide him to correct link to set cron.

Comment: I don't have access to cpanel :(